# How to insert/type key sequences that are mapped with imap

Tags: vim

I have just started using VIM. The one thing that stains me most while using VIM is the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. So after some googling I found this link: [Avoid the escape key](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key) and used it to map <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd>. I put this command in `_vimrc` file:

```
imap jk <Esc>
```

It's working fine. But now my question is if I need to type `jk` in vim, how should I do it. One way is to type something like `jik` then remove the `i`. But is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: Type the `j` then wait then type `k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to wait for the timeout, an alternative is pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> somewhere, i.e. either `<C-V>jk` or `j<C-V>k`. This key combination means "insert next char literally". (On Windows, you often need to use `<C-Q>` instead.)

Answer (score 1):

- Wait more than `timeoutlen` milliseconds (`:help timeoutlen`, `:set timeoutlen?`)
- Do something else in the meantime (as you suggest)
- Don't map key sequences that you're likely to type

`jk` is a common choice because no English words contain it. If your language does, don't use it, or change it to something you are not likely to bump into.

Comment: sometimes the obvious things just stare you at your face and yet you don't know what to do. Btw, what unit does the `timeoutlen` uses, milisecond?

Answer (score 1):

You can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>. For me this is easier than reaching for the escape key.
See:

:h i_CTRL-[

Comment: I am using VsVim, `Ctrl+[` doesn't work for some reason there.